# after migration in magento2 product add to cart error

Tags: magento2, migration

I have migrated from Magento 1.9.2.x to Magento 2.2.2 but when I click on the add to cart button, it gives this message:

> We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now.

Please check error in image also:

[image: ma]

Comment: Check  is there any active shopping cart rule migrated. That may prevent to add product to cart due to some error.

Comment: Check the error log in var/log directory and post that log here for the same !! that will help us to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Done,I have checked log and got error in table.
salesrule_customer_group table is not present .because of this "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now." comiing

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable third party plugins to check is it any conflict. First try to disable this one responsible for cart.

Similar situation here
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12129

Answer (score 0):

salesrule_customer_group table is not present in magento2.because of this "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now." coming...
This works for me